# jruby add RXTX serial listener

Tags: serial-port, jruby, inner-classes

I need to read a message incoming every 500ms from the serial COMx or /dev/ttySx interfaces under jruby.

What I am trying to do is to translate this [example](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Event_based_two_way_Communication) to Ruby in order to retrigger the listener.

I am learning jRuby so I started to activate the serial port and then I am trying to add the listener in this way:

```
java_import('gnu.io.RXTXPort') { 'JSerialPort' }

begin
 sp=JSerialPort.new('COM6')  
sp.setSerialPortParams(38400,8,1,0)
rescue 
  puts @error_message="myerror #{$!}"
ensure 
  sp.close
end
```

It seems to work.
Next is to add the listener which in the above example is described at this line

```
 serialPort.addEventListener(new SerialReader(in));
```

This is described [here](http://users.frii.com/jarvi/rxtx/doc/gnu/io/RXTXPort.html) where an addListener method is described.

I tried many ways to call the `addListener` methods, but I don't manage to call by jRuby such an inner method.

I tried `sp::RXTXPort::addEventListener` with no luck. Long research googling set me to stall (and some frustration).
Any help welcome.

Comment: did you try to import and extend SerialReader class from sample?

Comment: I decided to start again from scratch. My goal is to communicate via serial interface, bydirectional to a card sending a message every 500msecs.
This [article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/Serial_Java) convinced me I am using an alternate library, infact I could not find the mentioned methods.
According to this article I downloaded Javacomm libraries. Now next step is to call them as desctibed [here](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby)

Comment: Finally I managed to create a listener and properly receive the 172 bytes sent message. 
The code I wrote is [here](http://marcobenatti.blogspot.it/2012/11/jruby-serial-event-listener.html) just in case someone wants to save time.
NEXT STEP is make available the received message to the main application.